# displaying current logged user data

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

i need assistance on how i could possibly query a current logged in / signed in users data so i can display their specific data using the snippet of code below -

```
class AddStore extends StatelessWidget {
  AddStore({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  final CollectionReference _user =
      FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("users");

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: StreamBuilder(
            stream: _user.snapshots(),
            builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> streamSnapshot) {
              if (!streamSnapshot.hasData) {
                return const SizedBox(
                  height: 250,
                  child: Center(
                    child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                  ),
                );
              } else {
                return ListView.builder(
                    itemCount: streamSnapshot.data!.docs.length,
                    itemBuilder: ((context, index) {
                      final DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot =
                          streamSnapshot.data!.docs[index];
                      return Column(
                        children: [
                          Text(documentSnapshot['fullName']),
                        ],
                      );
                    }));
              }
            }));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the current user id i.e `FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid`  while querying the data from `users collection`. And this results in single document so you should avoid using `ListView`

Change the `StreamBuilder` to this

```
  StreamBuilder<DocumentSnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>>(
        stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
            .collection('users')
            .doc(FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid).snapshots(),
        builder:
            (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<DocumentSnapshot> snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasError) {
            return const Text('Something went wrong');
          }
          if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
            return const Text("Loading");
          }
          Map<String, dynamic> data =
              snapshot.data!.data()! as Map<String, dynamic>;
          return Text(data['fullName']);
        },
      )
```

Comment: when i try this   the solution above I get "The argument type 'Stream<DocumentSnapshot<Object?>>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Stream<DocumentSnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>>?'

Comment: Remove that then, see my updated edit

Comment: it now gives the error that 'data' is not defined defined for 'Object'

Comment: Do you actually have a document with our currentUser id ?

Comment: Try the updated code, this works perfect, I have tested myself

Comment: i saw my error , yes your code worked the problem was with user id , i thought doc id was similiar to uid

Comment: I'm glad to hear that it worked for you!